# TexLive 2015 - error when using "french" options with TexStudio

Tags: texlive, windows, french

I am new in the LaTex world. I just installed yesterday Texlive 2015 et texstudio (last version) on my windows 10 computer. Everything seems to be working properly except for the template "Article{french}" which refuses to compile any minimal working example.
The problem may come from the french option or Texstudio parameters. The "collection lang-french" and "babel-french" are installed. I checked in the TexLive manager. From that point I read all I can to find a solution without any success.

Here is what I wrote:

```
    \documentclass[french]{article}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{lmodern}
    \usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
    \usepackage{babel}
    \begin{document}
     test
    \end{document}
```

Here is the log file:

```
 % les options suivantes (conseillées) par défaut :
\abbreviations
\disallowuchyph
\overfullhboxmark
\tthyphenation
\tabbingaccents
\automaticlettrine
% désactivez les options de frenchle pour '«' et '»' !
% test eFrench = {\befr}
\newcommand{\fbefr}{{\footnotesize E}F{\footnotesize RENCH}}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\befr}{\fbefr}
```

I cannot understand what all this means as I have no knowledge on computer or software at all.

Would someone understand or had any solution to make my texlive usable in french?

Thank you very much !

---

The posted file ran without error until the recent update replacing `frenchle` by `e-french` in texlive. The file now generates

```
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/e-french/french.cfg
! Undefined control sequence.
l.2 \abbreviations
```

I'm using PdfLatex

Comment: You have shown a file with more tex source code, can you show instead the log file with the error?

Comment: I added The error to the question, this appears to be related to a recent update in texlive in the last few days.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

babel-french has now been updated to avoid this problem, so the fix suggested below is no longer needed.

---

This is an unfortunate incompatibility in a the e-french files recently added.

The simplest (temporary) local fix is to add an empty file `french.cfg` to the folder containing your document. This file will then be read instead of the `french.cfg` in the e-french distribution.

Comment: Or alternatively, load `babel` with option `noconfigs`.

Comment: An update to `babel-french`, that should be available by tomorrow (2015-08-21), should fix the issue. See http://tug.org/svn/texlive?view=revision&sortby=date&revision=38160

Comment: Adding an empty file french.cfg works for me. I wish I could understand why but I'm anyway happy it solves the problem. I also updated the babel-french package and it now works just fine. Many thanks for all your help !

Answer (score 5):

The error is due to the inclusion of `e-french` (formerly `frenchle`) in TeX Live. An update to `babel-french` solves the issue.

### Transcript when compiling the example with `babel-french` version 3.1g (TeX Live revision 37701)

```
> pdflatex manu
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.16 (TeX Live 2015) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./manu.tex
LaTeX2e <2015/01/01> patch level 2
Babel <3.9m> and hyphenation patterns for 79 languages loaded.
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/t1enc.def))
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/inputenc.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/utf8.def
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/t1enc.dfu)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ot1enc.dfu)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/omsenc.dfu)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lm/lmodern.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/geometry/geometry.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifpdf.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifvtex.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ifxetex/ifxetex.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/babel.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-french/frenchb.ldf
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/babel.def)
*************************************
* Local config file french.cfg used
*
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/e-french/french.cfg
! Undefined control sequence.
l.2 \abbreviations
```

### Transcript when compiling the example with `babel-french` version 3.1h (TeX Live revision 38160)

```
> pdflatex manu
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.16 (TeX Live 2015) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./manu.tex
LaTeX2e <2015/01/01> patch level 2
Babel <3.9m> and hyphenation patterns for 79 languages loaded.
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/t1enc.def))
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/inputenc.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/utf8.def
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/t1enc.dfu)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ot1enc.dfu)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/omsenc.dfu)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lm/lmodern.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/geometry/geometry.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifpdf.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifvtex.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ifxetex/ifxetex.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/babel.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-french/frenchb.ldf
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/babel.def)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/carlisle/scalefnt.sty)
No file manu.aux.
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lm/t1lmr.fd)
*geometry* driver: auto-detecting
*geometry* detected driver: pdftex
[1{/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]
(./manu.aux) ){/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/fonts/enc/dvips/lm/lm-ec.enc}
</usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/lm/lmr10.pfb>
Output written on manu.pdf (1 page, 23380 bytes).
Transcript written on manu.log.
```