# Slight package bug about Babel/efrench

Tags: pdftex, miktex, compiling, babel, french

I was writing in LaTeX, and when I'm trying to complie with MikTex, this prints:

> ("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\e-french\french.cfg" !
>   Undefined control sequence.

I believe it to be the source of the problem, since the file prints this:

> % les options suivantes (conseillées) par défaut : \abbreviations
>   \automaticlettrine % désactivez les options de frenchle pour '«' et
>   \disallowuchyph \overfullhboxmark \tthyphenation \tabbingaccents
>   '»' ! % test eFrench = {\befr} \newcommand{\fbefr}{{\footnotesize
>   E}F{\footnotesize RENCH}} \DeclareRobustCommand{\befr}{\fbefr}

Moreover, Texmaker specifies there's an error with \abbreviations, etc...

I tried to update but nothing helps.

EDIT: Here's a screencap
[image: Sample]

Putting the log as well:

> ("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\e-french\french.cfg" !
>   Undefined control sequence. l.2 \abbreviations The control sequence at
>   the end of the top line of your error message was never \def'ed. If
>   you have misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type`I' and the correct
>   spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue, and I'll forget
>   about whatever was undefined. ! Undefined control sequence. l.3
>   \disallowuchyph The control sequence at the end of the top line of
>   your error message was never \def'ed. If you have misspelled it (e.g.,`
>   \hobx'), type `I' and the correct spelling (e.g.,`I\hbox').
>   Otherwise just continue, and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
>   ! Undefined control sequence. l.4 \overfullhboxmark The control
>   sequence at the end of the top line of your error message was never
>   \def'ed. If you have misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type`I' and the
>   correct spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue, and I'll
>   forget about whatever was undefined. ! Undefined control sequence. l.5
>   \tthyphenation The control sequence at the end of the top line of your
>   error message was never \def'ed. If you have misspelled it (e.g.,`
>   \hobx'), type `I' and the correct spelling (e.g.,`I\hbox').
>   Otherwise just continue, and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
>   ! Undefined control sequence. l.6 \tabbingaccents The control sequence
>   at the end of the top line of your error message was never \def'ed. If
>   you have misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type`I' and the correct
>   spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue, and I'll forget
>   about whatever was undefined. ! Undefined control sequence. l.7
>   \automaticlettrine The control sequence at the end of the top line of
>   your error message was never \def'ed. If you have misspelled it (e.g.,`
>   \hobx'), type `I' and the correct spelling (e.g.,`I\hbox').
>   Otherwise just continue, and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

MWE 1:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book} 
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{ucs} 
\usepackage[french]{babel} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{amsfonts} 
\usepackage{amssymb} 
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{lmodern} 
\usepackage{kpfonts} 
\usepackage{fourier} 
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry} 
\author{John Doe} 
\title{My biography} 
\begin{document} 
  Bonjour, très chère ! 
\end{document}
```

MWE 2:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book} 
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} \usepackage[a4paper,left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry} \usepackage{lmodern} 
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage[french]{babel} 
\usepackage{fancyhdr} 
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor} 
\usepackage{mathtools} 
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage[framed, numbered]{mcode} 
\usepackage{url} 
\usepackage{natbib} 
\usepackage{float} 
\usepackage{chemfig} 
\usepackage{chemist} 
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}
```

Comment: A very vage problem description. Make a complete minimal example that demonstrates your problem.

Comment: Basically, I want to get rid of the red message since everytime I'm compiling I'm teleported at the tp of the document. The structure looks correct:

Comment: \usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

Comment: But idk what the problem is.

Comment: Make a **complete** example. Something I can try to check if I get the error too.

Comment: I don't get an undefined control sequence with this example. But it doesn't make sense to load kpfonts and fourrier, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/173743/latex-error-command-widering-already-defined.

Comment: I think it could be related to MikTex's recent updates. The package wasn't acting weird till I updated my distribution. I reinstalled it and it does the same thing. Should I downgrade? If so, how?

Comment: I have no idea what you should do as you didn't provide the needed information. Until now you neither showed the exact error message, nor a clear example, nor a log-file or some list of your package versions. Btw: Stop to put code in the comments. Edit your question.

Comment: Added a screencap and a piece of the log.

Comment: Imho your french/babel is too old. Did you run the update manager in user **and** in admin mode?

Comment: I ran both at the same time and no update available for the admin one. The user one asked me to upload chemfig and pcf but not babel.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer If you are interested in a minimal example that produces the error, try `\documentclass[french]{article}\usepackage{babel}\begin{document}\end{document}`. I can only speak for an up-to-date MikTeX here, however. The problem seems to be the same as [TexLive 2015 - error when using “french” options with TexStudio](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/262358/35864) (the temporary fixes suggested there work here as well), but the update promised there (which is available for TeX Live I assume) doesn't seem to have made it to MikTeX yet.

Comment: @moewe: The update has made it to miktex, your example works fine for me (and my miktex is up-to-date). Can you show me the log?  You can sent it by mail if you want.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Now that is interesting. I just removed the `e-french` package, and installed `babel-french` and now I don't get any errors any more. Unfortunately, I don't have the `.log` file of the failing run any more, but it looked very much like the log [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/262456/35864) (minus the TeX Live/MikTeX and Linux/Windows difference of course). My `babel` identifies as `Babel <3.9l>` though.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer A short correction on Babel, it says `<3.9l>` at the head of the `.log` file, but with `\listfiles` I get `babel.sty 2015/08/03 3.9`. I can only guess what went when I ran the example first, because I had just done an update a few minutes before (to the 2015/09/15 database) and there weren't even updates for French.

Comment: @moewe: babel should be version `<3.9m>` and `frenchb.ldf` version `v3.1h`. And I have both packages (e-french and babel-french) installed and it works fine. There was an older `frenchb.ldf` which tried to load the french.cfg from e-french and then gave errors (as french.cfg starts with `\abbreviations`). But my `frenchb.ldf` no longer tries to do it.

Comment: Anyway, this problem here seems to be the same as the one I linked to and should be solved by an update. Can you run `\listfiles\documentclass[french]{article}\usepackage{babel}\begin{document}\end{document}‌​` and report the `.log` file?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer That is what `\listfiles` reports now here as well (see my correction above), unfortunately I can't say what it said when it didn't work before (I guess the version of `french.ldf` would be interesting?), and I can't say what packages pertaining to French language support I had installed initially, except that I certainly had a `french.cfg` from `e-french`.

Comment: @moewe The code to load an optional `language.cfg` is in the babel core (in babel.def in `\ldf@finish`). The newest `frenchb.ldf` suppress actively that an existing `french.cfg` is loaded. So to get around the problem that the french.cfg from e-french gives errors you must either deinstalled `e-french` or get the newest `frenchb.ldf`.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I suppose I had an older version of `frenchb.ldf` and now I have v. 3.1h and it works while at the same time `e-french` is installed. I have no idea what went wrong when I tried the update. But that is not something we can find out now, I guess. Interestingly the problem in the question here seems related (at least if the OP really did all the updates in User and Admin mode).

Answer (score 1):

For me, the issue appeared when running "Update MiKTeX" in Admin mode and it disappeared, when I ran the "Update MiKTeX" again in User mode.